# Affect outbound interface selection in or after POSTROUTING chain?

Tags: iptables, routing

I have a system hosting a number of KVM instances.  All of these are connected to a single bridge (say, `brvirt`), to which is also connected `eth1`.  This layer 2 environment is on a private network using 172.16.10.0/24 for an address change.  There are two other interfaces on the system that we'll call `eth0` (10.10.10.10) and `eth2` (10.10.20.20).

In general, external connectivity is provided via `SNAT` to the address of `eth0` (and the hosts's default gateway is also out this interface).  For *some systems*, I want an explicit 1-1 `SNAT` rule on the 10.10.20.0/24 network, which is attached to `eth2`.

This is a problem because by the time we hit the `POSTROUTING` chain to perform the `SNAT` the outbound interface selection has already been made.  The kernel has already selected the default route (assuming a connection to anything other than a directly attached network), which means that when the `SNAT` rule modifies the source ip address, the local routing infrastructure drops the packet because it is originating on the wrong layer 2 network.

Is there any way around this?   What I *really* want to do is make routing decisions based on the source address on the packet at the conclusion of the `POSTROUTING` chain...but it's called `POSTROUTING` for a good reason.

Answer (score 2):

this can be done with simple policy based routing.

you will need a set of rules and routes with the schema:

```
ip rule add from 172.16.10.X iif brvirt lookup 200
ip route add default via 1.2.3.4 src 4.3.2.1 dev ethY table 200
```

Variables:

```
172.16.10.X = KVM's IP
200         = Example value for routing_table, has to be unique for each KVM
ethY        = either eth0 or eth2
1.2.3.4     = Example Gateway on iface ethY
4.3.2.1     = Example Source-IP for each KVM
```

This will route anything comming from `172.16.10.X` over the specified iface `ethY` with the Source-Address of `4.3.2.1`

You can also do it more complex with `fwmarks` but I dont think this is needed in this case.

You can verify the routes with: `ip route get iif brvirt from 172.16.10.X 8.8.8.8`.
This will display the route and output device the kernel would use for a connection from `172.16.10.X` to `8.8.8.8`.

Hope it answers your question,

f0o